# Defining a function with variable in subscript

Tags: maple, programming

I want to define function f_n:=x^n in maple in such a way that if i enter f_3 is should get x^3. i'm unable to do so, please help me in this regard. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm no Maple expert, but wouldn't `n->x->x^n` work?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of indeces - literal (`a__n`) and indexed (`a[n]`) - but neither works in the way you want as far as I know.

You can define a two variable function: `f:=(n,x)->x^n`. This should work the way you want. E.g. an $f_3(x)$ would be accessed as `f(3,x)`.

The two variable function will not show in indexed notation, but except for that it should provide what want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of using a procedure call of an *indexed* name.

```
f := proc(x)
  if procname::indexed then
    x^op(1,procname);
  else error "procedure name called without an index";
  end if;
end proc:

f[3](x);

           3
          x

f[-2](x);

          1
         ----
           2
          x

f[a](x);

           a
          x

f(x);
Error, (in f) procedure name called without an index
```

If you are operating in 2D Input mode in the Maple GUI (its default) then in the following way you can enter an indexed name that appears as a subscripted name. Example, for the 2D Input of f[3] to appear as f-subscripted-by-3 you can enter these keystrokes:

f CtlShift_ 3  ie. Ctl-Shift-underscore together

That is quite different from the keystrokes,

f __ 3 , ie. f__3

which produces a special kind of name that (by design) gets prettyprinted as subscripted.